# Google Chat API - Error loading configuration

Tags: deployment, chatbot, google-cloud-console, google-chat

I developed a bot in the google apps script editor. To use this functionality in the google chat I need to pass the deployment-id (after each deploy) to the Google-Chat API. Before some weeks it was possible to navigate to the following:
"Google cloud console >> API & Services >> Google Chat API >> configuration (tab)".

When I try to access this "configuration" tab I get the following
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkLgY.png)

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like an actual issue with the GCP platform, what happens when you hit on submit feedback?

Comment: Did this, but I think this is only for feedback itself and not some "help" :D

Comment: That definitely looks unexpected, if you have a Google Workspace account or cloud identity you could [request developer support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6103110)